# Get image dimensions in map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm trying to loop through and map a list of image URLs to `<img>` tags in React using the `.map()` function, but I'd like to class each image based on whether it's vertical or horizontal. Here's the code I have:

```
const images = ['path/to/image1.jpg', 'path/to/image2.jpg']
const imageList = images.map((imageSrc) => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = imageSrc
  let ratio = 1
  image.onload = () => {
    ratio = image.width / image.height
  }
  return <img src={imageSrc} className={ratio > 1 ? 'img_horiz' : 'img_vert'} />
})
```

When the page renders however, `imageList` is empty. Is there any way to retroactively append the vertical/horizontal classes to each image? Or is there a way to achieve this using the `.map()` function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can depend on the onLoad function, then change the className based on it. Check the following code: in the component you can add the following Function

```
onImgLoad = ({ target: img }) => {
        let ratio = img.offsetWidth / img.offsetHeight;
        img.className = ratio > 1 ? "img_horiz" : "img_vert";
      };
```

---------- let the function handle the onLoad event as follows

```
const images = ['path/to/image1.jpg', 'path/to/image2.jpg']
    const imageList = images.map((imageSrc) => {
      return <img src={imageSrc} onLoad={this.onImgLoad} />
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `new Image()` and then never returning it. I think you want to do something like this instead:

```
const images = ['path/to/image1.jpg', 'path/to/image2.jpg']
const imageList = images.map((imageSrc) => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = imageSrc
  image.ratio = 1
  image.className = 'img_vert'
  image.onload = () => {
    image.ratio = image.width / image.height
    image.className = ratio > 1 ? 'img_horiz' : 'img_vert'
  }

  return image
})
```

Comment: Don't think this will work. `.map()` needs to return a JSX element, not an `Image`.